# How can I update retrofit2(+OkkHttp) params if it was created like @Singleton with dagger2?

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2

I try create `Retrofit2` with `dagger2`:

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.e("loggingInterceptor", message));
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    OkHttpClient providesOkHttpClient(Utils utils, HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor) {
        User user = utils.getSettings();
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(Long.valueOf(user.getTimeOut()), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Retrofit providesRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Utils utils) {
        User user = utils.getSettings();
        String host = user.getHost();
        if (!host.endsWith("/")) host += "/";
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(host)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient).build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    RestApiFactory getRestApiFactory(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RestApiFactory(retrofit);
    }
}
```

But I have this options - User can open `Settings view` and change `baseUrl`, `timeOut` or `etc`. But my retrofit is `@Singleton` and I can not update this params. If I make it not `@Singleton` - I will create new instance for each request and it very bad. How can I recreate retrofit after user change settings?

Comment: You could use a dynamic url with `@Url`, instead of using  `.baseUrl(host)` in builder.

Comment: how can I change connectTimeout, readTimeout, writeTimeout?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. In that case, maybe the Retrofit creation should be in the "application code" instead of in the dependency injection code, and recreate Retrofit instance when user changes settings.

Comment: I thought about it. but it looks like not a good practice. especially since everything is beautiful with a dagger2.))) and only this small thing breaks everything.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it's also true that if the user can change that, it becomes logic business and shouldn't be in DI code IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subcomponent of the application component and you would then control the lifecycle of that subcomponent.

You would define a custom scope, for instance `@RetrofitScope` and add it to your subcomponent.

```
@ApplicationScope
interface AppComponent {
    // sub components
    fun retrofitComponent(retrofitModule: RetrofitModule): RetrofitComponent
}
```

Subcomponent:

```
@RetrofitScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [(RetrofitModule::class)])
interface RetrofitComponent {
    fun retrofit(): Retrofit
}
```

Submodule:

```
@Module
class RetrofitModule(/* pass any stuff you need */) {
    @Provides
    @RetrofitScope
    fun providesRetrofit(): Retrofit = /* TODO */
}
```

Then you initialize your subcomponent like so:

```
appComponent.retrofitComponent(RetrofitModule(/* pass args */))
```

When you want to change the implementation, instantiate a new subcomponent as above, with new arguments.

Comment: I already tried so. But I can not refer to the objects of the subcomponent in the main component

Comment: You can add accessor methods to the subcomponent, in the interface, which will be implemented by Dagger.